# Time dependent domain of an operator in Sobolev spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I have a question about the density of some subspace of $H^1(0,1)$ in it.
Let $\alpha$ be a continuous function on $[0,T] \times[0,1]$ where $T>0$ is a fixed positive number.

We consider the subspace of $H^1(0,1)$ $$V(t) = \left\{ {v \in {L^2}(0,1),{\rm{ }}{\partial _x}v + \alpha (t,x)v \in {L^2}(0,1)}, t\in[0,T] \right\}$$
My question is : does $V(t)$ dense in $H^1(0,1)$? Thank you.

Comment: That depends on the regularity of $\alpha$. Please give more details.

Comment: Let say that it is continuous in space and time. Is this is enough for the density?. Thank you

Comment: Several more remarks: 1) The time dependence is irrelevant, since $t$ is fixed. 2) The set $V(t)$ may even fail to be a subset of $H^1(0,1)$, or at least I don't see a simple reason why it should be a subset. 3) It depends on whether you mean continuous on $(0,1)$ or on $[0,1]$ in the space variable. In any case, please add additonal information to the question and not just in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of $V(t)$ is flawed. You cannot write $t\in [0,T]$ inside the set because $t$ is already fixed outside. I guess you mean
$$
V(t) = \{v\in L^2 : v' + \alpha(t,\cdot)v\in L^2\},\quad t\in [0,T].
$$
But if $v\in L^2$, then also $\alpha(t,\cdot)v\in L^2$ and so the condition $v' + \alpha(t,\cdot)v\in L^2$ is equivalent to $v'\in L^2$. Hence, $V(t) = H^1(0,1)$ for every $t\in [0,T]$.